# What is this weird machine code at the beginning of my C++ program and how do I remove it

Tags: c++, optimization

When I open my program in a hex editor, there is some weird code at the beginning that looks like some sort of debug information. When I disassemble it, it looks like this:

```
0:  f3 0f 1e fa             repz nop edx
4:  48 83 ec 08             sub    rsp,0x8
8:  48 8b 05 e1 3f 00 00    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rip+0x3fe1]        # 0x3ff0
f:  48 85 c0                test   rax,rax
12: 74 02                   je     0x16
14: ff d0                   call   rax
16: 48 83 c4 08             add    rsp,0x8
1a: c3                      ret
1b: 00 00                   add    BYTE PTR [rax],al
1d: 00 00                   add    BYTE PTR [rax],al
1f: 00 ff                   add    bh,bh
21: 35 e2 3f 00 00          xor    eax,0x3fe2
26: ff 25 e4 3f 00 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x3fe4]        # 0x4010
2c: 0f 1f 40 00             nop    DWORD PTR [rax+0x0]
30: ff 25 e2 3f 00 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x3fe2]        # 0x4018
36: 68 00 00 00 00          push   0x0
3b: e9 e0 ff ff ff          jmp    0x20
40: ff 25 da 3f 00 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x3fda]        # 0x4020
46: 68 01 00 00 00          push   0x1
4b: e9 d0 ff ff ff          jmp    0x20
50: ff 25 d2 3f 00 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x3fd2]        # 0x4028
56: 68 02 00 00 00          push   0x2
5b: e9 c0 ff ff ff          jmp    0x20
60: ff 25 ca 3f 00 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x3fca]        # 0x4030
66: 68 03 00 00 00          push   0x3
6b: e9 b0 ff ff ff          jmp    0x20
70: ff 25 c2 3f 00 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x3fc2]        # 0x4038
76: 68 04 00 00 00          push   0x4
7b: e9 a0 ff ff ff          jmp    0x20
80: ff 25 ba 3f 00 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x3fba]        # 0x4040
86: 68 05 00 00 00          push   0x5
8b: e9 90 ff ff ff          jmp    0x20
90: ff 25 b2 3f 00 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x3fb2]        # 0x4048
96: 68 06 00 00 00          push   0x6
9b: e9 80 ff ff ff          jmp    0x20
a0: ff 25 aa 3f 00 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x3faa]        # 0x4050
a6: 68 07 00 00 00          push   0x7
ab: e9 70 ff ff ff          jmp    0x20
b0: ff 25 a2 3f 00 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x3fa2]        # 0x4058
b6: 68 08 00 00 00          push   0x8
bb: e9 60 ff ff ff          jmp    0x20
c0: ff 25 9a 3f 00 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x3f9a]        # 0x4060
c6: 68 09 00 00 00          push   0x9
cb: e9 50 ff ff ff          jmp    0x20
d0: ff 25 92 3f 00 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x3f92]        # 0x4068
d6: 68 0a 00 00 00          push   0xa
db: e9 40 ff ff ff          jmp    0x20
e0: ff 25 8a 3f 00 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x3f8a]        # 0x4070
e6: 68 0b 00 00 00          push   0xb
eb: e9 30 ff ff ff          jmp    0x20
f0: ff 25 82 3f 00 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x3f82]        # 0x4078
f6: 68 0c 00 00 00          push   0xc
fb: e9 20 ff ff ff          jmp    0x20
100:    ff 25 7a 3f 00 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x3f7a]        # 0x4080
106:    68 0d 00 00 00          push   0xd
10b:    e9 10 ff ff ff          jmp    0x20
110:    ff 25 72 3f 00 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x3f72]        # 0x4088
116:    68 0e 00 00 00          push   0xe
11b:    e9 00 ff ff ff          jmp    0x20
120:    ff 25 6a 3f 00 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x3f6a]        # 0x4090
126:    68 0f 00 00 00          push   0xf
12b:    e9 f0 fe ff ff          jmp    0x20
130:    ff 25 62 3f 00 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x3f62]        # 0x4098
136:    68 10 00 00 00          push   0x10
13b:    e9 e0 fe ff ff          jmp    0x20
140:    ff 25 5a 3f 00 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x3f5a]        # 0x40a0
146:    68 11 00 00 00          push   0x11
14b:    e9 d0 fe ff ff          jmp    0x20
150:    ff 25 52 3f 00 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x3f52]        # 0x40a8
156:    68 12 00 00 00          push   0x12
15b:    e9 c0 fe ff ff          jmp    0x20
160:    ff 25 4a 3f 00 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x3f4a]        # 0x40b0
166:    68 13 00 00 00          push   0x13
16b:    e9 b0 fe ff ff          jmp    0x20
170:    ff 25 42 3f 00 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x3f42]        # 0x40b8
176:    68 14 00 00 00          push   0x14
17b:    e9 a0 fe ff ff          jmp    0x20
180:    ff 25 3a 3f 00 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x3f3a]        # 0x40c0
186:    68 15 00 00 00          push   0x15
18b:    e9 90 fe ff ff          jmp    0x20
190:    ff 25 32 3f 00 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x3f32]        # 0x40c8
196:    68 16 00 00 00          push   0x16
19b:    e9 80 fe ff ff          jmp    0x20
1a0:    ff 25 2a 3f 00 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x3f2a]        # 0x40d0
1a6:    68 17 00 00 00          push   0x17
1ab:    e9 70 fe ff ff          jmp    0x20
1b0:    ff 25 22 3f 00 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x3f22]        # 0x40d8
1b6:    68 18 00 00 00          push   0x18
1bb:    e9 60 fe ff ff          jmp    0x20
1c0:    ff 25 1a 3f 00 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x3f1a]        # 0x40e0
1c6:    68 19 00 00 00          push   0x19
1cb:    e9 50 fe ff ff          jmp    0x20
1d0:    ff 25 12 3f 00 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x3f12]        # 0x40e8
1d6:    68 1a 00 00 00          push   0x1a
1db:    e9 40 fe ff ff          jmp    0x20
1e0:    ff 25 0a 3f 00 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x3f0a]        # 0x40f0
1e6:    68 1b 00 00 00          push   0x1b
1eb:    e9 30 fe ff ff          jmp    0x20
1f0:    ff 25 02 3f 00 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x3f02]        # 0x40f8
1f6:    68 1c 00 00 00          push   0x1c
1fb:    e9 20 fe ff ff          jmp    0x20
200:    ff 25 fa 3e 00 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x3efa]        # 0x4100
206:    68 1d 00 00 00          push   0x1d
20b:    e9 10 fe ff ff          jmp    0x20
210:    ff 25 f2 3e 00 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x3ef2]        # 0x4108
216:    68 1e 00 00 00          push   0x1e
21b:    e9 00 fe ff ff          jmp    0x20
220:    ff 25 ea 3e 00 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x3eea]        # 0x4110
226:    68 1f 00 00 00          push   0x1f
22b:    e9 f0 fd ff ff          jmp    0x20
230:    ff 25 e2 3e 00 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x3ee2]        # 0x4118
236:    68 20 00 00 00          push   0x20
23b:    e9 e0 fd ff ff          jmp    0x20
240:    ff 25 da 3e 00 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x3eda]        # 0x4120
246:    68 21 00 00 00          push   0x21
24b:    e9 d0 fd ff ff          jmp    0x20
250:    ff 25 d2 3e 00 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x3ed2]        # 0x4128
256:    68 22 00 00 00          push   0x22
25b:    e9 c0 fd ff ff          jmp    0x20
260:    ff 25 ca 3e 00 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x3eca]        # 0x4130
266:    68 23 00 00 00          push   0x23
26b:    e9 b0 fd ff ff          jmp    0x20
```

Using the optimization options for g++ and the -s flag didn't help. Other programs don't have this and I want to remove it.

Thanks

Comment: Provide the c++ code that`s disassebled

Comment: I think you will [find explanation here](https://youtu.be/dOfucXtyEsU?t=2558). Basically this code will call resolve function placed in dynamic library.

Comment: When writing your C++ code, you rely on a number of things (like standard I/O streams) being properly set up before `main()` is called.  When a hosted implementation (like g++) produces an executable from C++ code and libraries (i.e. compiling and linking) there is some machine-specific code included in the executable to set those things up. Static data is also often stored somehow in the executable.  No amount of compiler optimisation settings will eliminate that code, since your code relies on it being executed.

Comment: You can trust, that all code the linker put inside your executable will be used. Mainly that is loading dynamic libraries, initalizer loops for data&bss, all the gloabl ctor/dtor stuff and some hooks for system specific things if needed. Nothing to fear about!

Comment: If you set your linker options so that the linker shows you everything it's doing, you'll see that in addition to the object files that are generated by compiling your source code, it links two additional things, usually another object file and a lib file. The lib file is the C++ standard library. The object file is the **startup code**; it has the entry point where execution begins, and it does whatever setup is needed to put the application into a runnable state; then it calls your `main` function; then, when `main` returns, it does whatever is needed to clean things up.